# Bulk creation + edit images

Tags: image-processing, canvas, imagemagick, html5-canvas, photoshop

I currently use photoshop + datasets to automatically create CTA buttons for testing on a clients website. The dataset often contains text and other changes like underline or background colour, as well as alignment and font formatting.

Typically these can run into the thousands, which photoshop handles very well but the task is technical and not graphical. For me photoshop is overkill for the task.

Is anyone aware of a solution that is more code-friendly? I am currently playing around with canvas on HTML and fabric.js. This allows me to manipulate a *template* image, and I hoping I can pipe in code to create a number of .png output images.

Comment: Could you perhaps through up the code you have tried? Generally it helps get to an answer that bit quicker. Welcome to SO!

Comment: Great - sorry for the long pause on response. I will try and cobble together a first attempt. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Canvas would be well suited to your automation**

First, create a base .png and then programmatically alter it in thousands of ways.

Save the results to appropriately named .png files.

You could even create an on-screen viewer that dynamically creates thousands of variations.  The client(s) could browse the dynamically created images and select the variations that interest them. That would eliminate the need for thousands of saved files.

Here are just a start of canvas commands you can use to automate:

Apply text:

```
context.font("italic 14pt Verdana");
context.textAlign = textAlign;              // left|right|center
context.fillText("anyText", x,y);
```

Underlines are just a bit trickier:

```
// use measureText to get the text width
var textWidth =context.measureText(text).width;    
// 1-time only, pre-calculate all the “Y” underline offsets for each font you use
var ULOffset=lookupULOffset(font,fontSize);
context.moveTo(x,y+ULOffset);
context.lineTo(textWidth,y+ULOffset);
context.stroke();
```

Change background color *or anything else that you've created a sub-layer for!*

Like Photoshop Canvas has an excellent set of compositing operations.

- Source-over
- Source-in
- Source-out
- Source-atop
- Lighter
- Xor
- Destination-over
- Destination-in
- Destination-out
- Destination-atop
- Darker (this has been deprecated for some reason??)

You also can apply an alpha when drawing a layer as well as an alpha while drawing any canvas shapes.

In addition, check online for many image filters that have been created for canvas.

And that's just be beginning...

Happy Automating!